# Compare two unrelated tables sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, arcgis

We're dealing with geographic data with our Oracle database.

There's a function called ST_Insertects(x,y) which returns true if record x intersects y.

What we're trying to do is, compare each record of table A with all records of table B, and check two conditions

```
condition 1 : A.TIMEZONE = 1 (Timezone field is not unique)
condition 2 : B.TIMEZONE = 1
condition 3 : ST_Intersects(A.SHAPE, B.SHAPE) (Shape field is where the geographical information is stored)
```

The result we're looking for is records ONLY from the table A that satisfy all 3 conditions above

We tried this in a single select statement but it doesn't seem to make much sense logically

Comment: Interesting. The *two* conditions are `condition 1`, `condition 2` and `condition 3`? Also, how do you plan to use the return value from your function, considering that plain SQL (Oracle implementation) is unaware of the Boolean data type? Make your function return 0 or 1 (NUMBER data type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the return value from your function in an Oracle SQL statement, you will need to change the function to return `0` or `1` (or `'T'/'F'` - some data type supported by Oracle Database, which does NOT support the Boolean data type).

Then you probably want something like

```
select <columns from A>
from   A
where  A.timezone = 1
  and  exists ( select * 
                from   B 
                where  B.timezone = 1
                  and  ST_intersects(A.shape, B.shape) = 1
              )
```

Answer (score 2):

pseudo-code that demonstrates a cross-join:

```
select A.*
from 
    tbl1 A, tbl2 B
where
    A.TIMEZONE = 1 and
    B.TIMEZONE = 1 and
    ST_Intersects(A.SHAPE, B.SHAPE)
```

if you get multiples, you can put a distinct and only select A.XXX columns

With a cross-join rows are matched like this

```
a.row1 - b.row1
a.row1 - b.row2
a.row1 - b.row3
a.row2 - b.row1
a.row2 - b.row2
a.row2 - b.row3
```

So if row 1 evaluates to true on multiple rows, then just add a distinct on a.Column1, etc.